# Parallel method calls like variable assignment

Tags: arrays, ruby

Variable assignment can be done like:

```
a, b = 1, 3
```

Given arrays:

```
a, b = [], []
```

is there a similar way to push multiple values into arrays so that it would be equivalent to this:

```
a << 1
b << 5
```

and would look something like:

```
a, b << 1 , 5
```

Comment: it's not fancy. it's confusing.

Comment: As comment avoid the use of parallel assignment for defining variables https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#parallel-assignment.

Comment: is there something you were trying to do? or were you just curious?

Comment: Just curious. I like to expand my knowledge of _how_ languages work; what I _can_ do with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no supported "parallel shovel" operator.

Parallel assignment exists because people commonly want to take multiple return values from a function and save them to variables for use later:

```
evens, odds = group_by_parity([1,2,3,4,5])
```

It's much less common to need to shovel each item from an array into a separate variable. If you really want to shovel the return values from a function into multiple variables without creating a new variable, you can do this:

```
group_by_parity([1,2,3,4,5]).tap do |results|
  evens << results[0]
  odds << results[1]
end
```

If you're feeling incorrigible, I suppose you could do this:

```
a[a.length], b[b.length] = 1, 5
```

But I can't think of a situation where that would be considered good code.

Comment: More so curiosity than good code practice. We all _should_ learn good coding practices along the way of our development paths however I like to learn what is possible, and why, more so than what should always be done because it should always be done. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @jkessluk glad to help! obviously as the person posting the code, it's important for me to add the disclaimer that it's bad code. but i absolutely support your curiosity and agree that it's valuable to learn the limits of a language ^-^